# Dynamic Update Query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update

I'm trying to create a standard UPDATE query for a table.  However, if certain criteria are met, some columns should be included/excluded from the UPDATE statement.

For example:

```
 UPDATE TBL_PROJECT SET
     REVISION_COUNT = V_REVISION_COUNT
    ,PRIMARY_BRANCH = IN_PRIMARY_BRANCH
    ,PROJECT_STATUS = IN_PROJECT_STATUS
    ...
  WHERE PROJECT_ID = IO_PROJECT_ID
  AND   REVISION_COUNT = IO_REVISION_COUNT
  RETURNING REVISION_COUNT INTO IO_REVISION_COUNT';
```

However, the table has two columns for submitted by and approved by.  So if the status is set to submitted or approved, I want those columns to be updated. eg.

```
IF IN_PROJECT_STATUS = 'SUB'
  UPDATE TBL_PROJECT SET
    SUBMITTED_DATE = SYSDATE
ELSIF IN_PROJECT_STATUS = 'APP'
  UPDATE TBL_PROJECT SET
    APPROVED_DATE = SYSDATE
END;
```

I also need to return the REVISION_COUNT and number of rows affected (rowcount) to check if the update was successful or not.

What is the best way to write this query?  I'm assuming a Dynamic query is better than having an if-elsif-else statement with the whole query nearly duplicated in each block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a single `UPDATE`, and use `DECODE` (or `CASE`) to only update the dates when `in_project_status` matches:

```
...
, submitted_date = DECODE( in_project_status, 'SUB', SYSDATE, submitted_date )
, approved_date  = DECODE( in_project_status, 'APP', SYSDATE, approved_date )
...
```

This would avoid the duplicate `UPDATE`.

Comment: @Matt McCormick: It's on 10g, use `CASE` instead of `DECODE`

Answer (score 2):

Case example:

```
UPDATE TBL_PROJECT 
  SET REVISION_COUNT = v_revision_count,
      PRIMARY_BRANCH = IN_PRIMARY_BRANCH,
      PROJECT_STATUS = IN_PROJECT_STATUS
      ...
      SUBMITTED_DATE = CASE WHEN IN_PROJECT_STATUS = 'APP' THEN SYSDATE ELSE SUBMITTED_DATE END,
      APPROVED_DATE = CASE WHEN IN_PROJECT_STATUS = 'SUB' THEN SYSDATE ELSE APPROVED_DATE END,
WHERE PROJECT_ID = IO_PROJECT_ID
  AND REVISION_COUNT = IO_REVISION_COUNT
RETURNING REVISION_COUNT INTO IO_REVISION_COUNT
```